# Windows Azure with no virtual machines can't delete storage

Tags: azure, azure-storage, azure-virtual-machine

I don't know how I had two virtual machines in Windows Azure, one application server that was stopped and one running database server, and all of a sudden, the machines no longer exist.

[image]

I have these questions:

1. is there a way to restore the machines?
2. if not is there a way to delete the storage?

Comment: In the future you can backup your vm config. Check here: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/silverlining/archive/2012/10/25/exporting-and-importing-vm-settings-with-the-azure-command-line-tools.aspx using the node.js tools, command would be "azure vm export vmname localpath"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can delete the storage with the help of steps specified in the below post

[Follow this post steps](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10969012/how-do-i-delete-an-azure-storage-account-containing-a-leased-blob)

Answer (score 1):

Go to Virtual Machines.
Click on Disks.
Click on any remaining disks.
Click on Delete Disk - there is an option to "retain", so make sure you choose delete.

Once all the disks are deleted, then delete the storage container.

Answer (score 0):

You may have hit a billing limit for a subscription with a limit. This typically happens with MSDN and Trial accounts. Once the limit is hit, Microsoft deletes any VMs running in the subscription. For IaaS VMs the actual disks still exist in storage and the VMs can be rehydrated from there once the account has some money in it or the monthly limit is reset by a new month starting. For PaaS instances, the package and configuration file is presumably still deployed to Windows Azure so, again, the service can be rehydrated when the account is flush with money.