# cannot delete Storage account

Tags: azure

Does anyone know solution to this?
I wonder if I need to contract MSFT support on this.

Using Azure Ruby SDK tried:
Created VM - worked
VM power OFF, power ON - worked.
Let it come up and tried to delete VM - failed at the last stage.

Here is what what VM delete produced:

Deleting deployment of cloud service "qa-sdk-ubuntu-2" ...
 succeeded (200)

Deleting cloud service qa-sdk-ubuntu-2. 
Waiting for disk to be released.

Deleting Disk "qa-sdk-ubuntu-2-qa-sdk-ubuntu-2-0-201402132358010165". 
http error 400

Also, then tried the same thing from portal and got 400 with the following message:

```
{""message":
  "Storage account qasdkubuntu2storageruvdl has container(s) which have an active image and/or disk artifacts. 
  Ensure those artifacts are removed from the image repository before deleting this storage account.",
  "ErrorMessage":"Storage account qasdkubuntu2storageruvdl has  container(s) which have an active image and/or disk artifacts. 
  Ensure those artifacts are removed from the image repository before deleting this storage account.",
  "httpStatusCode":"BadRequest","operationTrackingId":"ec03fe06212d61f49786aee29563a661","stackTrace":null,"Padding":null}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't remove your storage account, because it's storing the disk of your vm.

Here's a setup to remove it:

1-Log in to Windows Azure Managemente Portal

2-Virtual Machines

3-Disks and select the disk

4-click "Delete Disk".

after that, you can remove the storage account.

Comment: Yep, tried that and gives back the same 400 with the message (see original post with json body in it)

Comment: all references point to this solution: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10969012/how-do-i-delete-an-azure-storage-account-containing-a-leased-blob  http://manasbhardwaj.net/windows-azure-failed-to-delete-storage-account/  http://blogs.technet.com/b/danstolts/archive/2013/09/17/windows-azure-delete-storage-containers-disks-and-images-step-by-step.aspx

Comment: you can try a cmdlet with powershell too : http://blogs.technet.com/b/danstolts/archive/2013/09/17/windows-azure-delete-storage-containers-disks-and-images-step-by-step.aspx

Comment: Just tried solution for http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10969012/how-do-i-delete-an-azure-storage-account-containing-a-leased-blob and it solved the problem.
Thank you for your help.