# How can I delete a leased blob in Microsoft Azure storage

Tags: azure, azure-blob-storage, azure-storage, azure-virtual-machine

I created a virtual machine in Azure and then deleted it.
However, the associated storage account still exists.
I can't delete the storage account because it contains a container with a blob in it that has an indefinite lease.
Nothing else is using this storage account.
How can I delete this blob?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You need to delete the disk objects that are associated with the abandoned vhd's. You can do this easily in either the classic or new portal. Once you dispose of these (along with associated leases), you should be able to get rid of your storage account

In the Classic portal (`manage.windowsazure.com`), you just visit Virtual Machines, then Disks. Select a disk to delete, and click the trash can at the bottom of the screen.

[image: classic portal - disks]

In the new portal (`portal.azure.com`) you'll find the disks under `OS Disks (classic)` :

[image: OS disks in new portal]

From there, you can select and delete the disks from the VM's you deleted.

Comment: Yes, please go with this route.

Comment: Also see https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/storage-cannot-delete-storage-account-container-vhd/.

Answer (score 2):

You can Use Azure Cloud Explorer tool on Codeplex Open the Storage Account Delete all files inside that container,

Then you Can Delete the Container and the Storage Account Easily

Comment: The Azure Cloud Explorer is no longer maintained. 

Alternatives: Cloud Explorer in Visual Studio or Storage Explorer stand alone tool http://storageexplorer.com/

Answer (score 0):

One solution is to delete the container, whether through a GUI like a cloud explorer, tooling like Azure Storage Powershell, or using the rest API with an Azure Storage Client Library.

You don't need the blob lease to delete the container, which would also delete any blobs present in the container.

Comment: as long as the lease exists, the container can't be deleted.  Unless these GUIs have some special powers that the Azure Management Portal does not?