# Delete disk from Azure after VM deleted

Tags: azure, disk

All of the instructions available online for deleting a disk from a non-existent VM relate to the older Azure UI which does not contain the same menu commands as the new Portal. Therefore I need instructions for deleting an orphaned disk using the new Azure Management Portal. Instructions for the old portal are worthless for this action.

Comment: I answered this in a related-but-not-quite-duplicate question, [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/34364494/272109), including screenshot showing where the disks are located in the new portal.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Azure VM disks are stored in Azure Storage (blob containers).

Open http://portal.azure.com, click All Resources and locate the storage account, which you can manage there (for the entire account).

Or, to remove just that blob, get the Storage Explorer from here: http://storageexplorer.com/ - enter your credentials and use it to remove the required blob.

Comment: Using Azure Storage Explorer (thanks for the tip on this tool) I was able to delete one blob, but I have two others, images from vmdepot and bitnami, which I still can't delete. I'm not able to find information about resolving this error:   Failed to delete blob container.

More information:
There is currently a lease on the container and no lease ID was specified in the request.

Comment: @lynnjwalker - Refer to David Makogon's comment to your answer, that one shows how to handle leased blobs in the new portal.