# Azure: Unable to delete container, there is a lease on the blob but no lease ID provided

Tags: azure, azure-blob-storage

I have deleted everything but for a storage container which has a number of page and block blobs.  These won't delete as it says there is a lease and no lease ID is provided.
I have seen other posts about deleting VM disks.  I don't have any VMs now just these blobs left.
Thanks for taking a look.

Comment: And you've confirmed you have no disks listed, as described [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/34364494/272109)?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Please try the steps outlined in this article, and see if that solves your problem:

https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/storage-cannot-delete-storage-account-container-vhd/