# Storage account can not be deleted with resource group

Tags: azure, azure-resource-group, azure-storage-account

We wanted to delete a resource group that contained a VM with IP and storage account etc.

Everything got deleted except the storage account because of a vhd which says it still has a lease. I can't break the lease because of the following error message:

```
Failed to break lease on 1 out of 1 blob(s):
VM2X-20170518-074152.vhd: This blob is being used by the system.
```

Is there a way to break the lease, delete the blob with the lease active, or find out where it is leased to?

Additional Info:
On the vhd on the "Edit blob" tab, I get the following message:

```
File size of '137.44GB' exceeds max supported file size of '2.1MB.'
```

Comment: Have you looked under "Disks"? (you can search via All Resources in the portal) - then you can try deleting the disk in question. I answered a similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34364494/272109) - note - that was from a few years back, and the portal looked a bit different...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This sounds like a familiar problem with classic storage accounts, if it's the problem I think it is you will need to delete image using Powershell.

Set Storage account

```
$storageAccountName = "your storage account"
```

Check OS Disk image

```
Get-AzureVmImage | Where-Object { $_.OSDiskConfiguration.MediaLink -ne $null -and $_.OSDiskConfiguration.MediaLink.Host.Contains($storageAccountName)`
                           } | Select-Object -Property ImageName, ImageLabel
```

Check Data Disk image

```
Get-AzureVmImage | Where-Object {$_.DataDiskConfigurations -ne $null `
                                    -and ($_.DataDiskConfigurations | Where-Object {$_.MediaLink -ne $null -and $_.MediaLink.Host.Contains($storageAccountName)}).Count -gt 0 `
                                   } | Select-Object -Property ImageName, ImageLabel
```

Remove any image

```
Remove-AzureVMImage -ImageName 'yourImageName'
```

**Note**: commands are classic/ASM, make sure you have module installed.

Comment: Thanks, that might have helped, I got it deleted by migrating it to ARM and deleting it then, so I can't test your solution.

Comment: Then, that was your issue . You have to perform above steps to migrate.

Answer (score 0):

yes, you can use portal UI or powershell to break the lease (or SDK's). for the portal just click on the blob and there would be a button to break the lease. for powershell something like this:

```
$blob = Get-AzureStorageBlob -Context $ctx -Container %container% -Blob %blob%
$blob.ICloudBlob.BreakLease()
```

Comment: Thank you, I tried in the portal but got the error message above. I'll try in Powershell.

Comment: you dont need to edit blob, you need to go to the storage account, find the blob, click on it and click break lease button

Comment: Thank you, I broke the lease there but tried to delete the vhd afterwards instead of the blob

Comment: vhd is a blob. anything in azure blob storage is a blob. so your problem solved?

Comment: Sadly not. I deleted the container now but when I want to delete the Storage Account I get the error message `Storage account "search5022" cannot be deleted: "The storage account "search5022" has some active images and/or media, e.g. "WkV25326-WkV2-0-201705180543020779". Remove these images and/or media before deleting this storage account.". (Code: StorageAccountOperationFailed)`

Comment: delete those as well :)

Comment: There is no more container or blob inside the storage account. I'd delete them if I could find them

Comment: I neither have any VMs/Images or blobs left. There's only AzureDevOps and Azure AD left in the account.

Comment: I got it deleted now by migrating it to ARM and then deleting both the new resource group and the old resource group.