# Failure deleting storage in azure

Tags: azure, azure-storage

I'm trying to clean up after myself in azure, deleting everything.  If I go to https://portal.azure.com/ and select "All resources", I see one item: storage account (classic).  If I try to delete it, I get an error message:

`Failed to delete storage account 'xxxxx'. Unable to delete storage account 'xxxxx': 'Storage account xxxxx has some active image(s) and/or disk(s), e.g. xxxxx-xxxxx-os-##########. Ensure these image(s) and/or disk(s) are removed before deleting this storage account.'.`

I have no other resources, so I'm not sure how to delete this supposed in-use disk.  Clicking on the various menu options on the left, the only other item is a resource group (which I also can't delete, probably because of this storage account).  There are no items under "Virtual Machines" or "Virtual Machines (classic)".  (So, there are no disks to delete... unless I'm missing something.)  I've waited an hour and tried again, still with no success.

Any advice on how to delete this stubborn resource?

Related questions:

- [How do I delete an Azure storage account containing a leased blob?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10969012/how-do-i-delete-an-azure-storage-account-containing-a-leased-blob)
- [How can I delete a leased blob in Microsoft Azure storage](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34362904/how-can-i-delete-a-leased-blob-in-microsoft-azure-storage/34364494#34364494)

Comment: You have disk images still defined. See my answer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/34364494/272109) to see where they exist and how to get rid of them.

Comment: As I've mentioned, I have no VMs, and therefore no disks to delete.  Hence I don't believe that this is a duplicate.  Unless you can explain how I can find disks when nothing is listed under VMs.

Nevermind.  I read the pointed to link more closely, and see that it contains a different answer than what was presented in my original "related question".  Yes, this addresses my question.  Thanks.